# SQL How to select latest records with specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I trying to find answer by my own, but i cant do it.
I have table:

```
Id | val
1 | 4
2 | 5
3 | 4
4 | 6
5 | 4
```

I want to select last 2 IDs with value 4.
Output should be

```
Id | val
3 | 4
5 | 4
```

Comment: @Strawberry the lure of easy points outweighs the desire to adhere to and cooperate with the intended purpose of SO as stated on [this Web page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), including: _Don't ask about... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)_. That said, and in defense of the OP, it could be that he has absolutely no clue how to find an answer apart from asking here.

Comment: @strawberry Im just on mobile, i cannot sleep, looking for answers but cant find nothing.

Comment: At this point, 5 minutes (so, not hours) in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial would get you where you need to be - as the answers below so succinctly demonstrate.

Comment: Belive me, I spent more then 2 hours trying focus on that... SQL. Read all what's i found on W3. Trying using left join for no reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @Fahmi's query might be improved a bit:

```sql
SELECT id, val
FROM (
    SELECT id, val
    FROM your_tablename
    WHERE val = 4
    ORDER BY `id` DESC
    LIMIT 2
) AS t
ORDER BY t.id ASC
```

Demo - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb1227/1

Comment: Thanks, but why you use order?

Comment: I just find a lot of comments where ppl on stack says not to use order but use MAX(id) - 2 :\

Comment: Ok, thanks you a lot i just delete my questions becouse stack giv me warrning becouse that question suck.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below -

```
select id, val from tablename
where val=4
order by id desc limit 2
```